# How to send an acceptable response when trying to receive SMS with Twilio, Heroku, and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, twilio

So I had (most) of the following setup working on a Twilio test number last week.  I was running from localhost:300 using ngrok to receive the POST from twilio.  Everything worked great: didn't need blank-response.xml.erb, just rendered `:nothing => true` and the message came in and was handled by the controller - simple.

Today I am trying to deploy the app on heroku (and am switching credentials to a paid account) and keep recieving the following error in the Twilio console:

```
12200 Schema validation warning
Cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'html'.
```

I have tried rendering the xml response a half dozen different ways with the most textbook version outlined below.  My problem is the response **never** changes (from what's also listed below).  I don't know if I'm missing something stupid or if Heroku hates Twilio or what and I'm at a loss as to what to do at this point.  Any help is welcome!

## Code samples

url (Twilio webhook):

```
http://www.mycoolurl.com/confirmation
```

routes.rb:

```
post 'confirmation' => 'appointments#confirm'
```

appointments_controller:

```
def confirm
    incoming_message_body = params["Body"]
    from_number = params["From"]

    if incoming_message_body.downcase.match("yes")
        puts "CONFIRMED for #{from_number}"
    elsif incoming_message_body.downcase.match("no")
        puts "CANCELED for #{from_number}"
    end     

    render 'blank-response.xml.erb', :content_type => 'text/xml'
end
```

blank-response.xml.erb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response></Response>
```

Response from my Rails App:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Cool Website</title>
    <META name="description" content="some stupid blurb about this site">
    <META name="keywords" content="a bunch of cool keywords">
        </head>
        <frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
        <frame src="https://cool-name-24253.herokuapp.com/confirmation" frameborder="0" />
            <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
        </frameset>
        <!-- pageok -->
        <!-- 06 -->
        <!-- -->
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `render xml: ''`?

Comment: Same result.

Also tried:

Comment: What did you try? Your comment is empty after the colon. What do you mean by "result"? The HTML response? Next, try adding a `.xml` suffix to the request URL, i.e. `http://www.mycoolurl.com/confirmation.xml`.

Comment: If that does not solve your problem, please add the relevant portions from your Rails server log, i.e. everything from `Started GET` to `Completed` for that request. And please clearly state what the expected/required response should be. (Please don't assume we know twilio.)

Comment: I'm looking into this and I promise that Heroku doesn't hate Twilio, I've used it a bunch of times for different things. Are you actually using the Heroku URL though, as the HTML response, starting with an HTML4 doctype and including your Heroku URL in a `frame` just seems totally out of place to me.

Comment: Try adding `format: :xml` to your route?

Comment: @philnash:  The weird thing about this response is I don't know where it's coming from.  I am definitely using my actual domain and I didn't code any of that response.

Comment: @Raffael:  Sorry, I tried `render xml: "<Response>"` (an empty TwiML response), `@response = "<Response>" render xml: @response.to_xml`, `respond_with("<Response>")`

Comment: @engineersmnky: `format: :xml` produced the same error.

Comment: I feel like you only read the first sentence of my two comments. Why do I even bother?

Comment: @Raffael I tried your suggestions and they didn't work (thanks anyway).  Sorry I hurt your feeling but if you had bothered to read the question thoroughly you'd know what the expected response is.

Comment: kk, np. Got a bit frustrated because I felt like I could have helped if you had added that log excerpt to your question. Good luck!